# Migrate User Under Existing Firebase Auth Provider to Another

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created an app where users could sign-up through Facebook. However, I want to delete it altogether and replace it with just a Google sign-up.

For existing users, who signed up via Facebook only and have already accrued backend data in Firestore, is there any way I can manually add the "password" or "google.com" auth provider so the existing account remains untouched and the user can use as is after the fact I delete Facebook's login SDK?

Would these users have to create a new account with a new email address and start over. Or, would I need to keep Facebook's login SDK and corresponding account linkage code.

This is for less than 10 users. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the emails to be unique in your firebase configuration their facebook accounts would be linked to the google account as long as the email is the same. For different emails it would create a new account with the google email.

As an option, you could either keep the facebook login for now and ask users to link their accounts before you remove facebook login OR you could assign a "**default**" password to those accounts and mark that they need to be updated on first login.

For the second option, you need to use different passwords for each account though or people could try to reset other users passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Although I wanted to delete the FB SDK altogether, for the sake of time, I left it and just included code to link multiple auth providers via "google.com" or "password" for existing accounts originally signed-up through FB.